# How to extract video file from json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')) and save to folder

Tags: php

I need help in getting video from `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`  and save it into a folder. It only saved to MySQL but need to move it to a folder since it is not in this format `$_FILES["photo"]["name"]`

What I tried so far

```
 $targetdir = "videos/";
    $video_path = $postjson['video'];
    $dir = $targetdir.$video_path;
    file_put_contents('video/', $video_path);
```

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: Please research exhaustively.  Stack Overflow will have tens of pages on this subject.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan it was moving the file to the folder.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have searched through before asking the question.